# Can't seem to read from .txt in Java

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

I can't seem to create objects with variables from a .txt file, I have:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){

    ArrayList<Employee> ArrEmployee = new ArrayList<Employee>(); //  array for employee objects


     try {
            Scanner txtIn = new Scanner(new File("/Users/PatrickBui/Documents/workspace/COMP 249 - Assignment 3/src/payroll.txt"));

            while (txtIn.hasNext()) { // looping through the payroll.txt file and creating Employee objects from its data

                long EmployeeNumber = txtIn.nextLong();
                String EmployeeName = txtIn.next();
                String LastName = txtIn.next();
                double HoursWorked = txtIn.nextDouble();
                double HourlyWage = txtIn.nextDouble();

                    ArrEmployee.add(new Employee(EmployeeNumber,EmployeeName,LastName,HoursWorked,HourlyWage));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("fail to find file payroll");
        }
}
}
```

So far, I don't know what could make this go wrong. The payroll.txt is formatted as such:

```
31718 PHILLIP LENNOX 55.0 20.00
11528 NANCY TROOPER 40.0 10.45
16783 JOHN CONNAUGHT 30.5 10.00
10538 PETER DUNCAN 45.0 10.75
21O15 JAMES HAROLD 32.0 10.50
```

And I keep getting these errors when I run the program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextLong(Scanner.java:2222)
at java.util.Scanner.nextLong(Scanner.java:2182)
at Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

Ideas on why this is happening? My code seem in proper order and this is really baffling me.

Comment: The code looks fine. I can only assume that the input file is corrupt in some way. In fact, test it by replacing File with just a String source for the Scanner: `String file = "31718 PHILLIP LENNOX 55.0 20.00\n11528 NANCY TROOPER 40.0 10.45";  Scanner txtIn = new Scanner(file);`.  Works fine then, so must be the file I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have a letter `O` instead of a zero `0` in James Harold's ID

```
21O15
```

should be

```
21015
```

Answer (score 2):

Honestly I'd do it another way.  Read in a line, split on whitespace and then parse each piece.  It's little or no more code than what you have but gives you the ability to check each piece and correct problems.

Scanner requries very rigid data format and you can't fix things up as you go (For instance in the real world one or more of those lines would have a middle name which whould totally hose your scanner).

The problem with yours is probably something as simple as a leading empty line in your data or something like that.  If you want to keep working that way, try usign the "has" methods to see if it has a long available first and if not skip forward a little.